# Android Studio APK size doubled and dump_syms folder is the reason?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

First, my APK size was around 9 MB after some development in the project when I generated the APK I noticed its size has been doubled and when I analyzed the APK I could see the folder dump_syms is the reason takes around 8 MB as the follows:

[APK Analyze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vse05.png)

- No NDK support in the project
- No obvious CPP files in the project files
- no CPP lib
- Size has been doubled in both release and debug

Please support, how to at least know the dependency behind this change?
and please explain why there're Windows, Linux, and Macos in an android project?

Comment: I figured out the reason was using a joiner dependency to play with strings

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue and after removing the below dependency from the app gradle solved the issues and the APK size decreased by almost 10 MB.

Remove --> **implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-buildtools:2.8.1'**

- For crashlytics I was already using which I kept as it is.

**implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.2.11'**

Answer (score 0):

**I figured out the reason was using a joiner dependency to play with strings**